# fmemopen in MinGW

Tags: gcc, mingw

I'm trying to compile a code that uses the fmemopen function in MinGW. I found out the there is no equivalent function in MinGW. Are the any alternative functions that I can use. In case if you have written an equivalent function for fmemopen please help me out.

My requirement is that, I cannot save the content into temporary files. The data has to remain  within the application. So I'm not sure if the idea of creating a temp file and reading back will workout.

Thanks,
Sathish

Comment: possible duplicate of [fmemopen for mingw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307955/fmemopen-for-mingw)