# Is there fmemopen() in MinGW

Tags: file-io, mingw, memory-access

I'm trying to compile some code that uses the [fmemopen](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Streams.html) function in MinGW. I found out that this function is not available MinGW. I need a function equivalent to `fmemopen()`.

Are there any alternative functions that I can use?

Comment: Cannot you use pipes to implement this? Write to the pipe from one process and receive the written data in another process. You can store the data in the second process as per your requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there are no fmemopen equivalents on win32 because of missing functionality in the kernel, I think cygwin implements it using a temp file like this one: https://github.com/kespindler/python-tesseract/blob/master/util-fmemopen.c

Comment: The link https://doxygen.openinfosecfoundation.org/util-fmemopen_8c_source.html is broken as of August 2013.

Comment: @sherpya: The updated link is dead as well. Couldn't find any reference to `fmemopen` in the github repo.

Comment: updated again, just googled for "python-tesseract" "util-fmemopen.c"