# Is it possible to use functions that acts on FILE* on custom structures?

Tags: c

Very often I see libraries that implements their own stream functionalities, instead of using `FILE*`. The typical interface will have a close function, similar to `fclose()`, and several open functions, one of which usually mimics `fopen()` and one of which usually accepts a few callbacks that should be used to open/close the stream, read to/write from the stream.

As a reference, good examples of what I am talking about are
http://www.xmlsoft.org/xmlio.html or https://developer.gnome.org/gio/.

The approach, in general, seems very straightforward to me, however these libraries do not usually implement a replacement for all the functions in the standard library (e.g., `fscanf()`, `fprintf()`, ...).

Thus I wonder if an extension mechanism is available for standard library `FILE*` as well (e.g.: opening by providing callbacks for some low-level required functionalities). I was not able to find any reference about this capability, so I guess it is not part of any standard.

Anyway, here is my question: is this functionality available in the C standard library (any standard is fine, as long as it is portable)? If not is there any easy (i.e., it does not require to re-implement the whole stdio.h functions) option that allows to implement it on top of the standard library?

Comment: Most likely libraries like that just *wraps* the normal standard I/O functions, i.e. their private structure contains a `FILE *` member that the library uses internally. Either that, or it wraps the native operating systems functions (`open`/`close`/`read`/`write` on POSIX systems, `CreateFile`/`CloseHandle`/`ReadFile`/`WriteFile` on Windows).

Comment: Indeed they are wrapping FILE* when accessing files, but I was interested in the extension of what FILE* handles. Essentially I want to express my streams in term of callbacks that can retrieve/write data and still be able to use standard functions on top of this callback. The answer from @Geoff Reedy shows clearly what I am looking for.

Comment: Here are two related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307955/fmemopen-for-mingw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217690/is-there-no-fopencookie-or-fmemopen-in-mingw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the C library you're using. Glibc, for example, supports custom streams through [fopencookie](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-Cookies.html#index-fopencookie) ([further documentation here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Custom-Streams.html#Custom-Streams)). FreeBSD  (and probably other BSDs as well, including OS X) have [funopen](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=funopen&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+10.2-RELEASE+and+Ports). It doesn't look like Microsoft's C library supports such a feature.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.

So apparently there is indeed no standard, but some C standard libraries offer this functionality.

The answer is missing the portability requirement, but it already addresses many of the points.