# Concatenate two file pointers

Tags: c, file

I am looking for a function `FILE * join (FILE * a, FILE * b)` that is equivalent to `popen("cat a b", "r");`. That is, calling `join` should produce a new file pointer that contains all of file `a`, then all of file `b`.

Preferably `join` should be lazy such that file `b` is not read until all of file `a` has been consumed.

Comment: You are operating with wrong terms. You want a function to create a new file which is a concatenation of two other files. Apparently you are missing at least the desired name as the parameter.

Comment: I don't want to create a physical file on disk, but a virtual file in the same way that popen does.

Comment: define "virtual" file please ?

Comment: `popen` is creating a *pipe* to a created *process*.

Comment: @Tom's virtual in the sense that it is not an actual file that is stored somewhere, but a process that lazily produces the output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272652/is-it-possible-to-use-functions-that-acts-on-file-on-custom-structures

Comment: @BlackCap Using a FILE pointer to manipulate it ? Well, I will follow the question because it appear overcomplicated for me to have a FILE pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create a portable function for this. It is possible to do with `fopencookie` with Linux/Glibc or `funopen` on BSD. See: [Is it possible to use functions that acts on FILE* on custom structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272652/is-it-possible-to-use-functions-that-acts-on-file-on-custom-structures)  I am unaware of any method for this on Windows though.

You'd just need to provide a method for reading that would just try to read the given number of bytes from the first file handle that so far doesn't have end-of-file condition.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you could: at least while not creating a temporary file and wrapping the result in a `FILE*` that let you use the "normal" file-access functions like `fread()` etc.

The *logic* is easy enough: read from `a` until end-of-file, then read from `b` but you cannot "get inside" the `FILE*` handling routines (at least in a portable way, according to [Antti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52991710/2096401)) to get them to make the switch from one file to the other.

You *could* write a function(s) that replaced *specific* file-handling functions that took two `FILE*` arguments, e.g. you could define `fread2(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream1, FILE* stream2)` that accepted two streams, and read from one until it was exhausted, then switched to the other.

Or you could create your own `FILEPAIR` structure (returned/filled-in by `join()`) that held the references to the two `FILE*`s and then create dedicated reading functions that operated on that structure (e.g. `fread2(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILEPAIR *filePair)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my join function, please see [Antti Haapala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52991710/2302508) for compability issues.

```
typedef struct {
  FILE * a;
  FILE * b;
} myCookie;

ssize_t join_read(myCookie * cookie, char *buf, size_t size) {
  size_t s = fread(buf, 1, size, cookie->a);

  if (s < size)
    s += fread(buf+s, 1, size-s, cookie->b);

  return s;
}

int join_close(myCookie * cookie) {
  return fclose(cookie->a) | fclose(cookie->b);
}

FILE * join (FILE * a, FILE * b) {
  myCookie * cookie = malloc(sizeof(myCookie));
  cookie->a = a;
  cookie->b = b;
  return fopencookie(cookie, "r", (cookie_io_functions_t)
      { join_read
      , NULL
      , NULL
      , join_close });
}
```

Since this is already Linux specific, we can also define a function:

```
FILE * empty () {
  return fopen("/dev/null", "r");
}
```

Now file pointers form a monoid under `join` and `empty`!

Answer (score -1):

There is **no** such function. You need it to write yourself.

Comment: I am a complete C beginner. Could you elaborate on how I can create `join`?

Comment: @BlackCap try [this](https://codeforwin.org/2018/02/c-program-merge-two-files.html). This will create a third file. You may not want this, then you could just *read* the files, in a loop, first file `a`, then file `b`.

Comment: The link create a physical file on disk, which is not what I am looking for.